# How to force a refresh to load all nokia here map display tiles?

Tags: maps, here-api

I managed to force my map to recreate nokia map (my first map was created perfectly) by first checking whether there is any map created in the first place. If so, destroy it before creating another map object. (see the pseudo code snippet)

```
var map;
if(map is not empty)
    map.destroy();

map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(document.getElementById("map"),{....});
```

This code works but i have a problem.
The map only refreshes part of the screen. I have to manually move the map (by a little) to force it to refresh.

I tried map.update() method but it does not work.

Any advice?

So what can i do to force the entire map to load properly?

Comment: If not sure if it fixes your issue, but could you try using `map.pan()` to shift the map rather than manually moving the map?  i.e. `map.pan(0, 0, 1, 1);`

Comment: Can I know why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`map.update(-1, true)` will force the page to re render the map.